# Differences between data in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have tried to figure out why this happens but I have no idea why. I am going to post the code and then explain what happens. The issue is I do not know WHY this happens and it's annoying me like crazy!

Button:

```html
<a
  href="#"
  v-for="(userStories, userStoriesIndex) in storiesData"
  :key="userStoriesIndex"
  @click="openUserStories(userStoriesIndex)"
>
```

Which loads:

```html
<Stories v-for="(userStories, userStoriesIndex) in storiesData" 
  :key="userStoriesIndex"
>
  <Story v-for="(story, storyIndex) in userStories.stories" 
    :key="storyIndex"
    user-link="#"
    :name="userStories.model.name"
    :date="story.created_at"
    close-button
    @closeButtonClick="onCloseButtonClick"
  >
    <template #avatar>
       <img :src="userStories.model.profile_photo_path" />
    </template>
    <img :src="story.media.preview_url" />
  </Story>
</Stories>
```

And `storiesData` is loaded from this method:

```js
getStories() {
  axios
    .get("/stories")
    .then((response) => (this.storiesData = response.data));
}
```

which is loaded during `mounted()`

its loaded into:

```
data() {
        return {
            storiesData: [],
```

Now, when I click the button, the model loads incomplete, it is not loading the data... but... and this is where I lose it...

If I take the data from the Axios request, convert it to a JS object, and add it to the Vue file, everything works as intended.

I am not sure what's going on. I am completely at a loss why local would work and Axios would not. The data is IDENTICAL including but not limited to looking at Vue DevTools.

Comment: Where are you initially defining `storiesData`? With a typical _options API_ component, you'd need something like `data: () => ({ storiesData: [] })`. Are you using the _options_ or _composition_ API? What version of Vue are you using?

Comment: Added a comment with how its loaded into data @Phil - Also Im using Options

Comment: What do you see in your network tab? Exactly as what is inside the Vue devtools? Not sure how this would not be possible. Do you have a public github repo for that one?

Comment: Are you sure the data you expect is at the top level of the response JSON? Make sure that `response.data` is the array you expect

Comment: Nothing shows up in network, nothing shows up in Vue Devools except the expected data. Unfortunately it isnt public... if it helps, Ive stumped 10 people on this today... THE only thing people are suggesting is I move everything into setup

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan not really a relevant option. And you should debug why you don't see that one in network to start. Not sure how you can expect to receive something without receiving it. Try another browser in private window maybe.

Comment: @kissu ive tried that. All it does it shows the data exists in Vue, but does not load it. UNLESS I load it locally as an object in setup

Comment: You're repeating yourself here. Try to focus on the network part first, because this is the first link in the chain. If you can't get/see the data from the network tab, you don't need to go further. Once you'll find out about that one, we'll move forward.

Comment: @kissu sorry my bad for misunderstanding you. There are no errors in network is what I meant. All the data is there from start to finish. I’m truly stumped. If there is something specific you want to seek I’ll gladly show it to you.

Comment: You can probably wrap your data into ```<pre>``` tags in your template, double check that one and send us some screenshots of that one + network. Also, highlighting more precisely the differences (while keeping only the relevant parts of the payload).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249021/discussion-between-arcticmediaryan-and-kissu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound to me like a bad async handling, Axios (and any other AJAX library), send the request asynchronously. It look like you thought that the rendering would wait for the ajax request to finish, but it is not. Try convert the axios call into Async/Await:

```
async function getStories() {
  const data = await axios.get("/stories");

  return data;
}
```

or for short:

```
async function getStories() {
  return await axios.get("/stories");
}
```

then in your hydration function:

```
this.storiesData = await getStories();
```